# Why do SVD results from numeric.js and numpy disagree?

Tags: javascript, python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have an input matrix:

```
let t = [
      [0,1,0],
      [0,1,0],
      [0,0,0]
    ]
```

I want to compute its SVD using numeric.js:

```
let U = N.svd(t).U;
```

`U` is

```
[-0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865475, 0]
[-0.7071067811865475, -0.7071067811865475, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
```

I do same procedure using numpy:

```
A=np.array([[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]])
np.linalg.svd(A)[0]
```

Output:

```
[0.7071067811865475,   0,   -0.7071067811865475]
[0.7071067811865475,   0,    0.7071067811865475]
[0, 1, 0]
```

Is this a bug? This is not the only one time they differ in result. Which of them should I trust?

Comment: Do you know what an SVD decomposition is doing?

Comment: i want to find basis vectors for right nullspace in numerics js output they are not in the nullspace of A

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644327/how-unique-on-non-unique-are-u-and-v-in-singular-value-decomposition-svd).

Comment: thank you for useful reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SVD results there is some possible variation due to different algorithms. It is possible to have

- identical sign variations of full columns of U and V and
- identical permutations of columns in U and V when the corresponding singular values are identical. Indeed any kind of mixing by an orthogonal matrix might occur.

This happened both here. Your input is a rank-1 matrix, that is, 2 singular values are zero which explains the permutation of the last 2 columns. The sign flips are also obvious.

Comment: so to make things clear, n-r vectors in V, U does not guarantied to be in null/left null space of A?

Comment: In the usual algorithms, the singular values are in descending order so indeed the last `n-r` columns span the left and right null-spaces of the matrix. However which orthonormal basis of these null-spaces appear in these columns can differ from implementation to implementation.